# How to get class name from inside an attribute(which is in turn an object of some type)

Tags: python, class, attributes, aggregate, aggregation

I have a class that is aggregated in multiple other classes and when i reach one of this class' instances, i want to know to which class it belongs in order to access the right `do_stuff` function(I was thinking about some call like `Bar.do_stuff()`). In the example below i tried to simplify it. If there is a way to avoid getting the aggregator class name and still use it's functions in this situation that would be fine to. I would love a thing like `super()` that gives me the `cls.__name__()` of the class to which an attribute belong

Some simple example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val

    def which_class_am_i_part_of(self):
        cls = None  # How to get the class?
        print("I am an attribute of the class {}".format(cls))


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo(10)
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass



class Qux:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo(20)
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass


qux = Qux()
bar = Bar()
foo = qux.foo
foo.which_class_am_i_part_of()  # I am an attribute of the class Qux
foo = bar.foo
foo.which_class_am_i_part_of()  # I am an attribute of the class Bar
```

I want it to print this:
I am an attribute of the class Qux
I am an attribute of the class Bar
And i want it to scale well, for example if i include Foo in 100 more different classes, i want to able to get the class to which it belong no matter in which one it is (given that i have a reference to a Foo object)

Comment: This isn't something the attribute tracks. The reference to `foo` stored in `qux.__dict__` is just one of *many* possible references to `foo`. What would you expect `which_class_am_i_part_of` to return if `qux.foo is bar.foo` were true?

Comment: Part of the problem is the distinction between names and the objects that names refer too. `foo` and `qux.foo` are both names (ok, the second one is an expression, but close enough to a name for our purposes) that refer to the same object after `foo = qux.foo`. `qux.foo` could be thought of as an attribute name (since `qux.__dict__` contains a key `foo`), but that is *not* the same as the other variable `foo` created by your assignment.

Comment: Put yet another way, `foo = qux.foo` doesn't store any information  about which expression was used to initialize `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this automatically. The only way to do it would be to explicitly pass the owner on instantiation.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val, cls):
        self._val = val
        self.cls = cls

    def which_class_am_i_part_of(self):
        print("I am an attribute of the class {}".format(self.cls))


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo(10, self)
```